# Assigning static IP address to Debian machine?

Tags: networking, debian, ip, static-ip, ifconfig

I don't know how to use a static IP address on a Debian machine. Can anyone help?

I have the static IP address 83.222.248.100.

This is what I've tried:

```
$ cp /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces.bak
$ sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

And replaced:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

with the following text:

```
iface eth0 inet static
       address 83.222.248.100 
       gateway 83.222.248.1
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       network 83.222.248.0
       broadcast 83.222.248.255
```

(NB: I have no idea if those gateway/network/broadcast addresses are correct - can anyone advise?)

When I restart networking:

```
$ /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

I see:

```
Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces ... (warning).
Reconfiguring network interfaces...SIOCDELRT: No such process
```

And it hangs forever.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Verify that your netmask and gateway is correct. As we don't know where you got that address from, we can not really tell you how.

Comment: Thanks. How do I verify this? I got the static IP from my hosting provider: there's just a button saying 'Get static IP' and it gave me "83.222.248.100". Nothing else!

Comment: You're setting up a PC to be a router? What are you doing exactly? Remember that you've left a lot of network topology questions unanswered here.

Answer (score 1):

These two lines:

```
network 83.222.248.0
broadcast 83.222.248.255
```

are only necessary if you want to act as a router. To act as network peer you should only have address, gateway and netmask.

Comment: It seems SIOCDLRT is some kind of error removing a route from the routing table.  So my guess is that it's a routing problem.  If the user really wants to do routing, they better explain what they want to do a lot better than "I want to set up a static IP".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Debian for about six months, but perhaps you could try the following:

```
$ /etc/init.d/networking stop
$ /etc/init.d/networking start
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but with 'wlan0'.  Try putting 'auto eth0' before 'iface eth0 inet static'.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
   address 83.222.248.100 
   gateway 83.222.248.1
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   network 83.222.248.0
   broadcast 83.222.248.255
```